# how to check if the user belong to the specific group in powerapps (on load of the form)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, powerapp

we have a requirement to show "Approve" button on the load of the power apps form only if the user belong to the specific group

how can we achieve this requirement through power apps and MS flow?